# Understanding the process of setting up a Geth client on a private network and running a DApp

Tags: ethereum, go-ethereum, decentralized-applications, private-network, proof-of-work

I am a college student majoring in Computer Science.

I am currently using the Geth client with the 10.0.0.1 stable version and the Pow consensus algorithm.

I've set up three geth clients: one at IP address 13.115.72.160, another at IP address 54.168.207.61, and a third one at IP address 3.38.205.50, and connected these geth instances to form a private network.

Currently, I'm generating transactions in a dApp using the "ether account" (0x654cafbe1ad8006932f3bbc8641d206f40873762) associated with the geth client at 13.115.72.160.

Since the geth client at 13.115.72.160 is acting as a miner, does this mean that transactions initiated from the dApp first enter the mempool of the 13.115.72.160 geth client after undergoing UTXO validation(of course, ether = nonce check), and then these transactions are propagated to the other clients at IP addresses 54.168.207.61 and 3.38.205.50?

Even for transactions initiated from the ether account associated with the geth client at 13.115.72.160, they first enter the mempool of that same 13.115.72.160 geth client?

Am I understanding the flow of Fow of ethereum geth transaction flow?